# True or false: for all subsets $A$ and $B$ of $X, f(A\cup B) = f(A) \cup f(B)\,$?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, proof-verification

Can somebody prove For all subsets $A$ and $B$ of $X$, $f(A \cup B) = f(A) \cup f(B)$ ?

I believe that it is true, and here is my proof.  If somebody sees something I did wrong, can you please explain?

Take any $y∈F (A∪B).$  This means $\exists x∈A∪B : f(x)=y.$  Since $x∈A∪B,$ then     $x∈A$ or $x∈B,$ so $y=f(x)∈f(A)$ or $y=f(x)∈f(B),$ so $y∈f(A)∪f(B).$ Thus   $f(A)∪f(B)⊆f(A∪B).$

Take any $y∈f(A)∪f(B),$ so $y∈f(A)$ or $y∈f(B).$  Assume $y∈f(A).$  This means $\exists x∈A : y=f(x).$  Now $A ⊆A∪B,$ so $x∈A∪B,$ so $y=f(x)∈f(A∪B).$  This shows $f(A)∪f(B)⊆f(A∪B).$

Comment: Your proof is correct.

Comment: Thank you!  Can you tell me why proving that f(A)∪f(B)⊆f(A∪B) is sufficient?  I would have thought I would have to prove that f(A)∪f(B)=f(A∪B), but I guess proving the subset is adequate, though I am not entirely sure why this worked.

Comment: Your proof is fine, though at this level they may want you to explicitly say "without loss of generality" regarding your assumption that y is in f(A).

Comment: Oh I just spotted a mistake (which might explain your doubt): On the last line of the first paragraph you should have $f(A\cup B) \subset f(A) \cup f(B)$.

Comment: @OmarN you did prove both containments.

Comment: You can find links to several posts about this result [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/359693/overview-of-basic-results-about-images-and-preimages).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks great. One thing to point out in the second part: you assume that $y \in f(A)$. Technically, you also need to show that the other case works as well. That is, you technically need to show that even if $y \in f(B)$, we still arrive at the same conclusion that $y \in f(A \cup B)$. The proof is exactly the same as what you did however, and so you might even get away with saying something like: "without loss of generality, we may assume that $y \in f(A)$" or "a similar argument holds for the case when $y \in f(B)$".

Comment: Gotcha, makes perfect sense.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As John notes, your proof is correct, but I think it could be written more effectively. As you know, to prove $f(A\cup B)=f(A)\cup f(B)$, we must prove that $f(A\cup B)\subseteq f(A)\cup f(B)$ and $f(A\cup B)\supseteq f(A)\cup f(B)$ (i.e., $f(A)\cup f(B)\subseteq f(A\cup B)$).

**$(\subseteq)$:** Suppose $x\in f(A\cup B)$. Thus, $x=f(y)$ for some $y\in A\cup B$. Either $y\in A$, in which case $x\in f(A)$, or $y\in B$, in which case $x\in f(B)$. Thus, in either case, $x\in f(A)\cup f(B)$. This shows that $f(A\cup B)\subseteq f(A)\cup f(B)$.

**$(\supseteq)$:** Suppose $x\in f(A)\cup f(B)$. Then either $x\in f(A)$ or $x\in f(B)$. This means either that $x=f(y)$ for some $y\in A$ or that $x=f(y)$ for some $y\in B$. In either case, $x=f(y)$ for some $y\in A\cup B$, so $x\in f(A\cup B)$. This shows that $f(A)\cup f(B)\subseteq f(A\cup B)$.

We have shown that $f(A\cup B)\subseteq f(A)\cup f(B)$ and $f(A)\cup f(B)\subseteq f(A\cup B)$. By mutual subset inclusion, $f(A\cup B)=f(A)\cup f(B)$. $\blacksquare$

Comment: Thank you!  Though can you tell me why to prove $f(A\cup B)=f(A)\cup f(B)$, we must prove that $f(A\cup B)\subseteq f(A)\cup f(B)$ and $f(A\cup B)\supseteq f(A)\cup f(B)$ (i.e., $f(A)\cup f(B)\subseteq f(A\cup B)$)?  I am confused as to why to prove $f(A\cup B)=f(A)\cup f(B)$ , we don't try to prove $f(A\cup B)=f(A)\cup f(B)$

Comment: @OmarN Showing mutual subset inclusion to show that two sets are equal is a standard practice unless you can get away with doing some basic set algebra as in [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1227555/show-that-if-a-and-b-are-sets-then-a-cap-b-cup-a-cap-overlineb-a/1227562#1227562).